# Extracting information from ITunes Music Library XML with XSLT?

Tags: itunes, xslt-2.0, xslt

I need to extract information from iTunes Music Library.xml file. Since the xml is in the form of plist it has become a bit cumbersome.

I want to get list of all Track IDs from a specific playlist whose "Playlist ID" I have.

For example, An iTunes Playlist looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Playlists</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>Library</string>
            <key>Master</key><true/>
            <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>4053</integer> <!--Ex:4053 I have.-->
            <key>Playlist Items</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>2413</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>2083</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>2081</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>6798</integer>
                </dict>
                         </array>
                   <dict>
                   <!-- Here another playlist will start. with diff playlist ID -->
            <array>

</dict>
</plist>
```

You can check your Itunes Music Library.xml for details.

Basically, What I need is this.
(a) Given Playlist ID (here 4053), print all the Track Ids values (here: 2413,2083,2081,6798) under that playlist.

My attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" /> 

<xsl:template match="/"> 


<xsl:for-each select="plist/dict/array/dict">

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="child::integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Playlist ID']=4053"> 
           <!-- condition is not working fine, Below lines are working fine -->
        <xsl:for-each select="plist/dict/array/dict/array/dict">
            <xsl:value-of select="child::integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>


</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can any experts on XSLT help me out here. I will be very glad.

Comment: Please make a valid input XML, it is not a valid XML right now (closing tags missing). And it would be helpful if you show a sample desired output.

Comment: Hi "therealmarv", I have modified my question. Basically I am parsing itunes Music library.xml file. If you have itunes installed, You can check library xml to get better understanding of xml format. But I have explained it above. Thanks.

Comment: Mac OS X: (Path for Itunes Library File )
**/Users/username/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.xml**
Windows XP
**\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Music\iTunes\iTunes Library.xml**
Windows Vista
**\Users\username\Music\iTunes\iTunes Library.xml**
Windows 7
**\Users\username\My Music\iTunes\iTunes Library.xml**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was making a silly mistake and caught it. The path inside the for-each loop should be relative. I am posting the answer may be it may help somebody later.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" /> 

<xsl:template match="/"> 


<xsl:for-each select="plist/dict/array/dict">

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="child::integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Playlist ID']=4053"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="array/dict"> <!--**This should be relative**-->
            <xsl:value-of select="child::integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks.